# Cruze de Componenetes React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

No tengo idea de que pasa pero cuando modifico un componenete es otro la que se modifica, no se como explicarlo pero es ese el caso, tengo 2 calificadores, con el primero no hay problema pero el segundo no se modifica,

para saber que devolvia puse un `console.log` pero no pasa nada, mientras que en el primero le pongo el `console.log` alli si imprime, como es eso posible, si los eventos se ralizan en otro componente?

`FBCProduct` este es el componente que no funciona, que seria el segundo, pero si comento o quito el primero, comienza a funcionar sin problemas, porqué?, no entiendo, como un componente invoca `props` de otros?

```
  const [storepoint, setstorepoint] = useState(5);
  const [productpoint, setproductpoint] = useState(5);

<ModalBody>
          <FBCTienda
            pedido={pedido}
            storepoint={storepoint}
            setstorepoint={(tvalue) => console.log(tvalue)}
          />
          <FBCProduct
            producto={producto}
            pedido={pedido}
            productpoint={productpoint}
            setproductpoint={(pvalue) => setproductpoint(pvalue)}
          />
        </ModalBody>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta pasar como props las funciones modificadoras y actualizar los valores dentro de los componentes:

```
<ModalBody>
          <FBCTienda
            pedido={pedido}
            storepoint={storepoint}
            setstorepoint={setstorepoint}
          />
          <FBCProduct
            producto={producto}
            pedido={pedido}
            productpoint={productpoint}
            setproductpoint={setproductpoint}
          />
</ModalBody>
```

```
const FBCTienda = () =>{
const {setstorepoint} = props;
...
setstorepoint(1);
...
}
```